# Install Windows 10 on existing Ubuntu 18.04.5 on 2GB USB

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, usb, windows

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.5 as my only operating system. I'm looking to install Windows 10 alongside of it. I only have a 2GB USB Flash Drive. Is it possible to install it through the 2GB Flash Drive, or alternatively through somehow using a partition of my hard drive as a bootable ISO? And if so, how?

Comment: Borrow a 5GB USB from a friend. Be sure to back up your data to another media, since the Windows installer tends to assume that it's allowed to reformat the entire drive. Beyond that, this seems a Windows support question, not Ubuntu-related.

Comment: I have booted Ubuntu and *official* flavor ISOs from disk easily (both as ISO on a file-system, or the ISO written to a partition); selecting at `grub` (allowing me to run tests on hardware which didn't have a working USB port), but you're asking about an off-topic OS (windows 10 which uses a different ISO format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Installing Windows 10 without USB using Ubuntu GRUB

- **Backup the Target drive**. This method might overwrite it. Normally Windows is installed before Ubuntu.
- Download Windows ISO to your computer.
- Create a 6GB NTFS partition on the hard drive and extract the Windows ISO to it.
- Create a 20GB, or larger, NTFS partition on the hard drive for the Windows Installation.
- Open Disks, (Gnome-Disks), and note Device, (/dev/sdx), and UUID of the Windows ISO extract partition.
- For msdos partition table, copy the following menuentry to `/etc/grub.d/40-custom/`*:

```
menuentry 'Windows Recovery Environment (on /dev/sda4)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-592C85254E2CD0B7' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos4'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos4  592C85254E2CD0B7
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 592C85254E2CD0B7
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
    ntldr /bootmgr
}
```

- Edit menuentry, changing `sda4 to sdax`, `msdos4` to `msdosx` (4 places), and 592C85254E2CD0B7 to UUID, (3 places), to suit step 4 above.
- Run `sudo update grub` confirm that `ntldr /bootmgr` appears in grub.cfg.
- Boot the computer into the newly created Windows menuentry and install Windows into it's new partition.
- Reinstall Ubuntu if desired, the GRUB bootloader will have been replaced with the Windows bootloader.

*For gpt partition table, copy the following menuentry to `/etc/grub.d/40-custom/`:

```
menuentry 'Windows Recovery Environment (on /dev/sda4)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-592C85254E2CD0B7' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,gpt4'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  592C85254E2CD0B7
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 592C85254E2CD0B7
    fi
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
    ntldr /bootmgr
}
```

**Boot selecting Windows from the GRUB menu and follow the instructions.**

**Limitations**

Windows 10 has limitations with respect to partition tables and boot modes.

I was able to install Legacy mode Windows to a drive with a MSDOS partition table.

I was able to install UEFI mode Windows to a drive with a GPT partition table.

I was not able to install Legacy mode Windows to a drive with a GPT partition table.

I was not able to install UEFI mode Windows to a drive with a GPT partition table and Legacy mode Ubuntu.

There may be workarounds that are outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: Thank you! Seemed to be working smoothly until I finally was about to boot into the newly created partition.. “error: unknown argument ‘hidden-‘. error: can’t find command ‘drivemap’. error: invalid EFI file path. error: can’t find command ‘ntldr’.“  Video for clarification https://youtu.be/Uj6BvQlQiKw

Comment: It looks like it is not finding the location of the extracted Windows files on you hard drive. On my BIOS mode computer they were on root='hd0,msdos4' and UUID 592C85254E2CD0B7 on my UEFI boot computer they were on root='hd0,gpt1' and UUID 5642BC722509341F. look in Gnome-Disks to confirm the numbers for the location of the Windows files on your computer

Comment: I've double checked it, and it seems like I got the partition location correct?

Here's the 6GB partition: https://imgur.com/a/VwjFjle
Here's the content of the 6GB partition: https://imgur.com/a/y6rZUZ9

Here's my 40_custom file: https://justpaste.it/2bekb

I'm kind of a newbie when it comes to disk management, so bear with me haha

Comment: You need to **extract** the Windows ISO files to the disk, not just move the ISO there. I use Archive manager.